# Method requestClass::validate does not exist. How to call right provider?

Tags: validation, request, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.8.4, Dingo package for making api and I'm trying to use third party package pearl (https://packagist.org/packages/pearl/lumen-request-validate) for form request validation because Lumen doesn't support it.

I've set up everything and validation logic: rules and messages works fine when I define them in class(through postmen I receive "this field is required" etc ), but when everything is fine, when all fields are OK (from frontend side) I got this message

```
{
    "message": "Method App\\Http\\Requests\\StoreVehicleRequest::validate does not exist.",
    "status_code": 500,
    "debug": {
        "line": 102,
        "file": "E:\\Damjan\\Programiranje\\PHP\\Laravel\\Lumen\\automoto-lumen\\vendor\\illuminate\\support\\Traits\\Macroable.php",
        "class": "BadMethodCallException",
        "trace": [
            "#0 E:\\Damjan\\Programiranje\\PHP\\Laravel\\Lumen\\automoto-lumen\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Provider\\LumenServiceProvider.php(58): Illuminate\\Http\\Request->__call('validate', Array)"...
```

What I see here that trace leads to dingos LumenServiceProvider where i have

```
 $this->app->afterResolving(ValidatesWhenResolved::class, function ($resolved) {
            $resolved->validate();
        });
```

and I think this one should use pearls RequestServiceProvider, where I have.

```
 $this->app->afterResolving(RequestAbstract::class, function ($resolved) {
            $resolved->validateResolved();
        });
```

Or I'm missing something here. Struggling with this whole day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out what is going on. RequestServiceProvider is called but after it also Dingo is running LumenServiceProvider witch has an issue with Validator what is shown here

https://github.com/dingo/api/pull/1654/files

So I'm not sure I did the right thing, but this is my solution: 
because there is no publishing in Lumen, and I couldn't make it to work with third party packages I've copied LumenServiceProvider in my Provider folder, make a changes, and I've registered it in bootstrap/app.php.

It works for now, hopefully won't make any other problems.